# Format validation with regex in Rails gets: 'undefined local variable or method'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, validation, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Product model that has an :image_url attribute I'm trying to validate:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  validates ​:image_url​, allow_blank: true, ​format:
    { with: /​​\w+\.(gif|jpg|png)\z/i,
      message: "Image must have GIF, JPG, or PNG extension"
    }
end
```

The purpose of format validation is to allow all urls finishing with .gif, .png or .jpg. The regex seems to be working fine, here is the Rubular link: 
http://rubular.com/r/GQx0oAaI1x 
But when trying to access my application (any view or console) I'm getting:

```
undefined local variable or method `image_url​' for #<Class:0x007f84c9baf0b8>
```

This is my schema:

```
create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "title"
  t.text "description"
  t.string "image_url"
  t.decimal "price", precision: 8, scale: 2
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

All products present in my database have proper `image_url`. I don't understand why the error tells me `image_url` is an unknown method for `Class` and not for `Product object`.

This is my server log:

```
Started GET "/products" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-09-05 14:09:55 +0200
Processing by ProductsController#index as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 21ms (ActiveRecord: 3.8ms)



NameError - undefined local variable or method `image_url​' for <Class:0x00007fc3651c1e40>:
  app/models/product.rb:5:in `<class:Product>'
  app/models/product.rb:1:in `<main>'
  app/controllers/products_controller.rb:7:in `index'
```

This is my index action in ProductsController:

```
def index
  @products = Product.all
end
```

And this is my `index.html.haml`:

```
%h1 Your Pragmatic Catalog
%ul.catalog
  - @products.each do |product|
    %li
      = image_tag(product.image_url)
      %h2= product.title
      %p
        = sanitize(product.description)
      .price
        = number_to_currency(product.price)
```

Could anybody help me understand where the problem is?

I'm using ruby 2.5.1 with Rails 5.2.1.

Comment: Can you share the code where you are getting the error?

Comment: Error takes me to `app/models/product.rb, line 5` which is where the format validation starts (I skipped several lines of simple presence validations of other object attributes). Is that what you meant?

Comment: Are you sure the `image_url` field exists? couldn't it be that you forgot to run the migration? the validation code LGTM

Comment: can you post the error trace from the server log ? @JWilk

Comment: have you tried if it works without the `allow_blank`?

Comment: 1. This is my console when I comment out the validation:
`2.5.1 :003 > Product.first.image_url
      Product Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" ORDER BY "products"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
     => "dcbang.jpg"` 
2. I tried without `allow_blank` and without `message`
3. Will post the error trace in a moment

Comment: @JWilk can you show us the code from the controller where you fetch product(s) from the database and from the view where you are displaying it?

Comment: It might sound silly but can you try to restart the rails server and check if the error still occurs?

Comment: Try to change the validation to this ` validates ​:image_url​, allow_blank: true, ​format: { with: /​​\w+\.(gif|jpg|png)\z/i, message: "Image must have GIF, JPG, or PNG extension"}, on: [:create, :update]` so it will be validated on create/update the product only.

Comment: @MoamenNaanou I tried, the error is still the same.

Comment: @MrShemek I restarted the server a couple of times before posting the question unfortunately:(